# How can I speed up "OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor" in my web app?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, lazy-loading, interceptor

I'm building a web application (WAR) using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, JPA 2.0, and JBoss 7.1.1.Final.  I want to lazily load some objects in my controller (before it serves up the view), and so thought I'd give the "OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor" a whirl.  I configured this in my SPring application context file …

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    …
    <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/contracts/*"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor">  
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
            </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I have these entities that I want to lazily load …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cb_contract")
@Cacheable
@DataTransferObject
public class Contract implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Product product;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Organization org;
```

My controller tries to access these fields very simply …

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doGetUpdate(final HttpServletRequest request,
                                final Model model,
                                @PathVariable final String id)
{
    String nextPage = "landing";
    final Contract contract = m_contractService.findById(id);
    if (contract != null)
    {
        final ContractForm contractForm = new ContractForm(contract.getProduct(), 
        ...
```

Unfortunately, when I try and access my JSP page it takes about 20 seconds to load (it only took 2 seconds before).  It seems like something in Spring is repeatedly "Looking for a JTA transaction to join" and "Obtaining JDBC connection" for every entity on the page, not just the entities with things I want to lazily load.  Is there something I can do to configure this better and make it faster?

Thanks, - Dave

**Edit:**  Here are the configs.  Using Spring 3.1, I don't need a persistence.xml file.  Here is the entityManagerFactory ...

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.mainco.springboard" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="show_sql" value="true" />
    <entry key="dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
</util:map>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

I use the default transaction manager that accompanies JBoss 7.1.1.Final.  Here's the datasource

```
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb_db</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>my_db</user-name>
                    <password>my_db</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Comment: can you post your entityManagerFactory config + persistence-unit + transactionManager config ?

Comment: @ben75, I edited my question to include the Spring entitymanagerfactory configuration and the JTA datasource, as defined in the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The connection release mode when using JTA + Hibernate is by default set to "after_statment". I think this is why you get all those logs.

What I can suggest you is to change this default to "on_close" or "after_transaction" by specifying the following parameter in hibernate config :

```
hibernate.connection.release_mode="on_close"
```

All possible values for the `hibernate.connection.release_mode` are `after_transaction` , `after_statement` and `on_close`

Comment: With or without that property, the app is still taking a really long time (aroundn 15 seconds) to load the page.  It seems like Hibernate is scanning all entities loaded on the page, even ones without lazy associations.  I see messages like "DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Country{id=DZ, name=Algeria}"